# VARCHAR2 to TIMESTAMP conversion in ORACLE 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-timestamp

I have a column in table A as

```
select create_time from table_a;
```

The value is

```
08-MAR-19 08.23.47.897000000 PM GMT.
```

This column has been marked as VARCHAR2 for some business purpose. Now I am trying to get this column and convert the value to TIMESTAMP for some purpose, like this as below:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(create_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS.FF AM') from table_a;
```

But I am getting error:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

Can someone help me to convert this varchar data to timestamp. The reason I am trying to do is, I need to convert this time from one timezone to another :
eg:

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(create_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS.FF AM'), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'CET' from table_a;
```

Comment: The `GMT` at the end of your string is the problem. You need to `substring` your input to get rid of that.

Comment: Why are you storing `create_time` as a string instead of as a proper timestamp? What business purpose requires the wrong data type and data integrity and performance issues that can cause? And are the values always GMT? (Are you sure it *is* actually a string, and that isn't just how your client is displaying a timestamp, via your NLS settings?)

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole, yes I know that this column is actually a varchar field. The reason is that the client does not want to loose out any info incase of wrong data. There is no performance issue, as this table has a archive table and the data is less than 100 records per run.
The  time value is receive in a different timezone ( product does not allow to change db timezone to the client timezone..) hence the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> select replace('08-MAR-19 08.23.47.897000000 PM GMT','GMT','') AS RESULT from dual 
  ;

RESULT
--------------------------------
08-MAR-19 08.23.47.897000000 PM

SQL> select to_timestamp(replace('08-MAR-19 08.23.47.897000000 PM GMT','GMT','')) as RESULT from dual ;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
08-MAR-19 08.23.47.897000000 PM

SQL> select from_tz(to_timestamp(replace('08-MAR-19 08.23.47.897000000 PM GMT','GMT','')),'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'CET' AS RESULT from dual ;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
08-MAR-19 09.23.47.897000000 PM CET

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

The four characters  `GMT` at the end are not accounted for in your format string

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('08-MAR-19 08.23.47.897000000 PM GMT', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS.FF AM') from dual;
```

The following takes care of that:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(substr(create_time, 1, LENGTH(create_time) -4), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS.FF AM') t from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
select  TO_TIMESTAMP( REPLACE(ts, 'GMT', '')) from test_timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `GMT` using `REPLACE`

```
WITH A AS (SELECT REPLACE('08-MAR-19 08.23.47.897000000 PM GMT','GMT','') AS D FROM DUAL)
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (D, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS.FF AM')
  FROM A
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like:

```
to_timestamp(replace(create_time ,'GMT', null))
```

relies on your NLS settings, both for the timestamp format - particularly that it has an RR year mask - and the language for the month abbreviation. It would be safer to do:

```
to_timestamp(replace(create_time, ' GMT', null),
  'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
```

If the time zone isn't always GMT, but is always a valid and recognised region (not BST, for instance) then you might want to preserve the full date/time including that zone:

```
to_timestamp_tz(create_time, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM TZR',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
```

If you want that as a plain timestamp you can cast it, possibly changing to a specific zone first:

```
cast(to_timestamp_tz(create_time, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM TZR',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as timestamp)
```

or

```
cast(to_timestamp_tz(create_time, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM TZR',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') at time zone 'Asia/Tokyo' as timestamp)
```

or normalised to UTC (which won't affect GMT values, of course, as they're essentially the same):

```
sys_extract_utc(to_timestamp_tz(create_time, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM TZR',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f9bc8552f5b04e4048ba5068cfa3d583)